# Why PrintWriter is often use with FileOutputStream when I just can use the print method

Tags: java, fileoutputstream, printwriter

If I can do this:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("file.txt");
pw.println("Hello");
```

Why PW is often use like this:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("file.txt"));
pw.println("Hello");
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PrintWriter` constructors that accept a file name  or a `java.io.File` are relatively new; they were added in JDK 1.5. The `FileOutputStream` or `FileWriter` version used to be the only alternative; a lot of people don't even know about the new constructors in `PrintWriter.`

Comment: Ok, that explain why I saw that in Beginngs Java Objects, 2nd edition.